# Are homomorphisms a finite group?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question from my homework that says:

Find all the homomorphisms φ:ℂ->ℂ such that for any $x$ in ℝ: φ($x$) = $x$

I don't even know how to begin. The field of complex numbers is infinite. The number of homomorphisms must be huge, if it is even finite. How am I supposed to find them all??

Comment: Do you mean field homomorphisms?

Comment: The questions says "Find all the homomorphisms such that..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would think there are infinitely many such homomorphisms but you would be wrong. In fact there are only two! This is essentially the beginning of Galois theory in that what you are being asked to find is the Galois group Gal$(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$.

Ok so let $\tau$ be such a homomorphism.

Then it's action on $\mathbb{C}$ is defined as follows:

$\tau(a+ib) = \tau(a) + \tau(b)\tau(i) = a + \tau(i)b$

since $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau$ is known to fix those.

So now it remains to find $\tau(i)$. What do we know about $i$? We know that $i^2=-1$ of course.

Aha but $-1$ is real, and $\tau$ fixes that!

So lets consider $\tau(i)^2$.

$\tau(i)^2 = \tau(i^2)=\tau(-1) = -1$.

Thus $\tau(i)=\pm i$.

So we get two possible homomorphisms, one being the identity ($\tau(i)=i$) and one being complex conjugation ($\tau(i)=-i$).

It is easy to check that both of these work.

Answer (score 3):

If it is at least ring homomorphisms that you are looking for then $\varphi$ must satisfy:
$$
\varphi(a+bi)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(bi)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)\varphi(i)=a+b\varphi(i).
$$

Comment: Ok that is getting us somewhere, but still the problem remains. there are infinite values for $\varphi(i)$ that are valid. Basically anything goes.

Comment: @OriaGruber: Compute $\varphi(i)^2$.

Comment: $\varphi(i)^2 = \varphi(i) * \varphi(i) = \varphi(i^2) = \varphi(-1) = -1$

Comment: @OriaGruber: Do you know many numbers that square to $-1$?